# Why disallow re-using the same value in a format! macro

Tags: rust

Given:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{0} {0:?}", 10);
}
```

I get:

```
main.rs:2:27: 2:29 error: argument redeclared with type `?` when it was previously ``
main.rs:2     println!("{0} {1:?}", 10);
                                    ^~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I am forced to do:

```
println!("{0} {1:?}", 10, 10);
// OR
println!("{} {:?}", 10, 10);
```

Why is such a limit imposed upon me?

Answer (score 6):

It's due to a limitation in the formatting system.

Internally, `println!` (more accurately, [`format_args!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#format_args!)) packs its arguments into an array, pairing each argument with its formatting type. For example, the following expression:

```
println!("{2} {0:?} {1:x}", 1, 2, 3);
```

produces this argument array:

```
match (&1, &2, &3) {
    (__arg0, __arg1, __arg2) => [
        ::std::fmt::argument(::std::fmt::Debug::fmt, __arg0),
        ::std::fmt::argument(::std::fmt::LowerHex::fmt, __arg1),
        ::std::fmt::argument(::std::fmt::Display::fmt, __arg2)
        ]
}
```

(By the way, you can see the full expansion using `rustc -Z unstable-options --pretty=expanded main.rs`)

This explains why your example doesn't work: if you wanted the first argument (`__arg0`) to be *both* `Debug` and `Display`, then where would you put the second type?

There's no way of lifting this restriction without complicating the system too much, so sadly we'll just have to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not disallowing you from re-using the same value:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{0} {0}", 10);
}
```

works just fine.

The issue is what the error message says:

```
argument redeclared with type `?` when it was previously ``
```

You're trying to use the same argument as two different types, and that's not cool. I'm not 100% sure why it's not, but it's not.

Comment: Probably because `println` is macro, and this is evaluated on compile time. So if some value should be used with 2 different types, then it is natural, that there will be error.

Comment: @steve I can do `"{0} {0:#X}".format(10)` in Python

Comment: @steve I should have mentioned that I'm aware that what you do is legal, sorry.